# How to get exponential values into given float data type values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get exponential value only 2.34534563633563E+15 using below query. But it shows all below values and it is wrong.

ex:

```
SELECT [value] AS FloatValue
FROM #InvalidData
WHERE [Value]  like  '%E+%'
```

results:
    FloatValues

```
2.34534563633563E+15
3452345
23453456363
34534564
```

Please let me know how get only (1st one) exponential value.

Comment: First cast as decimal or integer, then to varchar. (If you don't like the float format.)

Comment: You know `mysql` and `sql-server`are 2 very different things? So delete the unrelated tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to get values representation as a string includes an "E".  If so, your code should actually work based on the *default* representation, although I prefer an explicit cast:

```
SELECT [value] AS FloatValue
FROM #InvalidData
WHERE CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(255)) LIKE '%E+%';
```

This doesn't work, because you are not using the *default* representation.

Instead, just use a numeric comparison:

```
where value >= 100000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @jarlh, one solution is to `CAST` two times : first to an `INTEGER`, then to a `CHAR`.

```
SELECT 2.34534563633563E+15, CAST(CAST(2.34534563633563E+15 AS SIGNED) AS CHAR);
```

Yields :

```
2.34534563633563e15 2345345636335630
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

> STR(number, length, decimals)

where 
**number** is Required. The number to convert to a string,
**length** is Optional. The length of the returning string. Default value is 10,
**decimals** is Optional. The number of decimals to display in the returning string. Default value is 0

for `SELECT STR(2.34534563633563E+15, 20, 3)`
result will be: 2345345636335630.000

Comment: Thank you for responding.. But we are not converting the exponential value to decimal or some other data types. I want to get the exponential value by using select query like above example.

Comment: Sir your first line said "I am trying to convert 3452345 (float) to varchar. " that's why i thought you should give it a try,but its fine if it's not worth it:)